# Will default route('/') add to the Navigator Stack when app loads

Tags: dart, flutter

As a example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp(),));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          child: Text('Go Back'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Screenshot of the above example:

[image]

I know that I can stop that behaviour using `Navigator.canPop(context)`.

My simple question is, When app launches with one page, will default route `"/"` add to the `Navigator` list?

[image]

If default route pushes to the `Navigator` stack(as shown in the above image) will it pop from the `Navigator` stack when press **Go Back**(in above example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [doc for Navigator class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html):

> A MaterialApp is the simplest way to set things up. The MaterialApp's
>   home becomes the route at the bottom of the Navigator's stack. It is
>   what you see when the app is launched.

Read below inline comments of [app.dart file source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/9fe53b0d2bb091535c16689cab705c95eac1c53d/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart#L172):

```
/// The widget for the default route of the app ([Navigator.defaultRouteName],
  /// which is `/`).
  ///
  /// This is the route that is displayed first when the application is started
  /// normally, unless [initialRoute] is specified. It's also the route that's
  /// displayed if the [initialRoute] can't be displayed.
  ///
  /// To be able to directly call [Theme.of], [MediaQuery.of], etc, in the code
  /// that sets the [home] argument in the constructor, you can use a [Builder]
  /// widget to get a [BuildContext].
  ///
  /// If [home] is specified, then [routes] must not include an entry for `/`,
  /// as [home] takes its place.
  ///
  /// The [Navigator] is only built if routes are provided (either via [home],
  /// [routes], [onGenerateRoute], or [onUnknownRoute]); if they are not,
  /// [builder] must not be null.
  ///
  /// The difference between using [home] and using [builder] is that the [home]
  /// subtree is inserted into the application below a [Navigator] (and thus
  /// below an [Overlay], which [Navigator] uses). With [home], therefore,
  /// dialog boxes will work automatically, [Tooltip]s will work, the [routes]
  /// table will be used, and APIs such as [Navigator.push] and [Navigator.pop]
  /// will work as expected. In contrast, the widget returned from [builder] is
  /// inserted _above_ the [MaterialApp]'s [Navigator] (if any).
final Widget home;
```

Yes, when added a widget to `home` property, that will add to the `Navigator` stack which means when call `pop` in that page, will remove/pop default route from the `Navigator` stack.

Notice: according to [this issues in github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/8307), do not try to `pop` initial route/page(default route).